# Rails getting ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I'm getting the following error in a Rails app (doing a GET request for an image that doesn't exist:):

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png"):
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
...
```

It looks like a known error in jquery-ui.css

These sites talk about it:

[jquery-ui.css images](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-css-images)

[Fixed jQuery UI CSS and image location to work with minified assets](https://github.com/fwenzel/reporter/commit/d6b3cd8)

And

[Bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=607759)

I have jquery-ui.css in my stylesheets folder.  It is this version: /*! jQuery UI - v1.9.2 - 2012-11-23

Line 246 has:

```
url(images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png)
```

But, I don't know how to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you can resolve this by viewing your `jquery-ui.css` and/or `jquery-ui.theme.css` and finding the line that is pointing to and removing `images` at the start so therefore it would look like this.

```
url(ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png)
```

instead of:

```
url(images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png)
```

Its looking at the wrong path therefore you will receive this error.

Answer (score 7):

Rather than modifying the hardcoded url path, you'd be better looking at [The Asset Pipeline Rails Guide (css and sass)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass) and using one of the listed asset pipeline helpers.

That way, using the `image-path("asset.png")` syntax, your referenced asset will always be correct.

Comment: This worked for me, but also had to change the file name from .css to .css.scss

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just change the path to the image, or ensure it is present in your /public/assets/images directory?